# How extract an incomplete url from string in c#

Tags: c#, regex, url

I am trying to extract some incomplete URLs from strings. Let me give you an example of what I mean by incomplete URL:

```
tny.sh/FJFCG8w
gka.co/cte3
google.com
cdn.ne/ecoe3
```

I have checked a bunch of solutions that use regex to detect the prefix like HTTP and stuff. but the above-mentioned links are links without prefixes. so does it possible to do it?

This is the method that I have tried to extract the URLs with it in a string:

```
protected LinkedList<string> ExtractLink(string txt)
{
    var linkParser = new Regex(@"\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    LinkedList<string> urls = new LinkedList<string>();

    foreach (Match m in linkParser.Matches(txt))
        urls.AddFirst(m.Value);

    return urls;
    }
```

And this is an example of calling the method:

```
ExtractLink("Hello, this is the link that you need to check tny.sh/FJFCG8w");
```

Comment: I see one good approach : use Regex. I can make one for you but I need a few rules for determining whether it is or not a "incomplete url"

Comment: Hervé, can I be useful to help you do it?

Comment: The question was closed :( I can't answer it anymore

Comment: Hervé, I am really stuck and can't ask any more question (Question Limit Reached), can't share somewhere else?

Comment: use this regex instead `[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=])*`

Comment: there is some error in '\' character (the visual studio underline them)

Comment: Add a @ before your string declaration `@"regex-here"`, it tells the compiler to ignore escapes

Comment: Hervé, you can add it as an answer and I will mark it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex instead

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=])*
```

If you also want to match the urls with the http(s) protocol use this

```
(https?:\/\/)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=])*
```